# how to generate a full website stylesheet based on 2 colors given by user?

Tags: php, css, forms, sass, less

I've been asked to build a form, that asks for a foreground and background color, then create a stylesheet for a website based on those two colors. I'd like to be able to make shades of the colors for different parts of the site, and for hover states etc...

I think LESS or SASS would be used for this but not sure where to start.

Comment: What have you tried in coding? And you need css...what you are talking about here is OOCSS....not sure how that has to do with what you want.

Comment: A good starting point would be looking at the documentation of either Sass or LESS (installation, usage, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, you can achieve this with [less variables](http://lesscss.org/#-variables). Take this lessCSS example, let's say `styles.less`:

```
@primaryColor: #c00;
@secondaryColor: #ddd;

body{
  background: @secondaryColor;
}

a{
  color: lighten(@primaryColor, 10%);
}
```

So what you want is to override the `@primaryColor` and `@secondaryColor` variables with input from the user. If you're using the [lessphp compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/):

```
$less = new lessc();
$less->setFormatter('compressed');

$lessData = array();

// get the styles
$lessData[] = file_get_contents('/path/to/styles.less');

// override variables (don't forget to validate input)
$lessData[] = sprintf('@primaryColor: %s', $_POST['primaryColor']);
$lessData[] = sprintf('@secondaryColor: %s', $_POST['secondaryColor']);

// compile to CSS
$css = $less->compile(implode("\n", $lessData));

file_put_contents('path/to/cache.css', $css);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `SASS` with PHP functionality, your best bet is to use [PHPSass](http://www.phpsass.com).

Read the documentation and try the demo.

**Example**

As a demo requires two colors:

```
$red: #f00;
$blue: #232;

body {
    background: $red;
    color: $blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LESS and JavaScript for setting the colors. You can do something like that :

```
@color1: `document.getElementById("Color1")`;
@color2: `document.getElementById("Color2")`;
```

While using an input field like that for exemple :

```
<input type="text" id="Color1"/>
<input type="text" id="Color2"/>
```

The you can use the variables in your style sheet

```
body
{
    background: @secondaryColor;
}
.randomClass 
{
    background: @secondaryColor;
}
```